# Summation of a List Using Foldl

Tags: haskell, fold, foldleft

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to implement the sine approximation using MacLaurin's series using foldl on Haskell. I've already generated the list, and now I'm trying to get the summation using fold.

This is my code. I know I'm doing something wrong with the sin function, but I'm not sure what to do. I also have to pass x. If sin receives x as input, list will use the same value of x.

```
factorial n = product [1..n]
list x = [-1**n * ((x**(2*n+1))/factorial(2*n+1)) | n <- [0..29] ]
sin x = foldl (+) 0 list x
```

SOLVED: 
Correct solution:

```
factorial n = product [1..n]
list x = [(-1)**n * ((x**(2*n+1))/factorial(2*n+1)) | n <- [0..29] ]
sine x = foldl (+) 0 (list x)
```

Comment: I didn't try, but maybe `foldl (+) 0 (list x)` ? Otherwise `factorial(2*n+1)` is an integer and the division is not valid.

Comment: Wow. It worked! Haha, I can't believe it's that simple. Thank you! :)

Comment: Why not use `sum` ?

Comment: This is for class! We're required to use foldl :)

Comment: If you can afford using [`foldl1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl1) then you don't even need the zero value.